Unable to verify ecDSA signature between cryptography libraries. BoncyCastle FIPS C# and System.Security.Cryptography
I've been looking to replace some cryptography services that use the standard .NET implementations to the BouncyCastle FIPS C# library. I've got RSA and PSS working but I'm struggling to understand an issue with Elliptical Curve.
As some groundwork and to better understand the library, I set up tests to verify that data signed with the standard .NET implementation can be verified using the FIPS library and that I can correctly load keys from JSON and X5092s.
I can load keys generated into both libraries and sign and verify data using both. However, if I sign something with the .NET implementation, I cannot verify it with the FIPS library, and vice versa.
As far as I can see, I'm not missing any parameters, but my cryptography knowledge is more practical than anything, so I may be missing something.
    [Fact]
    public void SignVerifyWithFipsAndDotNet()
    {
        
        FipsEC.KeyGenerationParameters originalKeyGenParameters =
            new FipsEC.KeyGenerationParameters(FipsEC.DomainParams.P384);
        
        FipsEC.KeyPairGenerator originalKpGen =
            CryptoServicesRegistrar.CreateGenerator(originalKeyGenParameters, new SecureRandom());
        
        var originalEd25519Keys = originalKpGen.GenerateKeyPair();

        var ecParameters = new ECParameters()
        {
            Curve = System.Security.Cryptography.ECCurve.NamedCurves.nistP384,
            Q = new System.Security.Cryptography.ECPoint()
            {
                X = originalEd25519Keys.PublicKey.W.XCoord.GetEncoded(),
                Y = originalEd25519Keys.PublicKey.W.YCoord.GetEncoded()
            },
            D = originalEd25519Keys.PrivateKey.S.ToByteArrayUnsigned()
        };

        // Ensure that the parameters match
        originalEd25519Keys.PrivateKey.S.ToByteArray().Should().BeEquivalentTo(ecParameters.D);
        originalEd25519Keys.PublicKey.W.XCoord.GetEncoded().Should().BeEquivalentTo(ecParameters.Q.X);
        originalEd25519Keys.PublicKey.W.YCoord.GetEncoded().Should().BeEquivalentTo(ecParameters.Q.Y);
        
        var ecdsa = ECDsa.Create(ecParameters);
        
        var cert = new CertificateRequest("SN=test", ecdsa, HashAlgorithmName.SHA384)
            .CreateSelfSigned(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(2));
        
        var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello, World!");
        
        // Sign DOTNET
        var dotNetSignature = ecdsa.SignData(message, HashAlgorithmName.SHA384);
        
        //SIGN FIPS
        var fipsSignature = generateECDSASignature(originalEd25519Keys.PrivateKey, message);
        
        // Verify Each using own verify method
        cert.GetECDsaPublicKey().VerifyData(message, dotNetSignature, HashAlgorithmName.SHA384).Should().BeTrue();
        verifyECDSASignature(originalEd25519Keys.PublicKey, fipsSignature, message).Should().BeTrue();
        
        //VERIFY FIPS using DOTNET (FAILS)
        cert.GetECDsaPublicKey().VerifyData(message, fipsSignature, HashAlgorithmName.SHA384).Should().BeTrue();
        
        //VERIFY DOTNET using FIPS (FAILS)
        verifyECDSASignature(originalEd25519Keys.PublicKey, dotNetSignature, message).Should().BeTrue();
    }

    public static byte[] generateECDSASignature(AsymmetricECPrivateKey key, byte[] message)
    {
        ISignatureFactoryService signatureFactoryProvider =
            CryptoServicesRegistrar.CreateService(key, new SecureRandom());
        
        ISignatureFactory<FipsEC.SignatureParameters> signer =
            signatureFactoryProvider.CreateSignatureFactory(FipsEC.Dsa.WithDigest(FipsShs.Sha384));
        
        IStreamCalculator<IBlockResult> calculator = signer.CreateCalculator();
        Stream sOut = calculator.Stream;
        sOut.Write(message, 0, message.Length);
        sOut.Close();
        return calculator.GetResult().Collect(); }

    public static bool verifyECDSASignature(AsymmetricECPublicKey key, byte[] signature, byte[] message)
    {
        IVerifierFactoryService verifierFactoryProvider = CryptoServicesRegistrar.CreateService(key);
        
        IVerifierFactory<FipsEC.SignatureParameters> verifier =
            verifierFactoryProvider.CreateVerifierFactory(FipsEC.Dsa.WithDigest(FipsShs.Sha384));
        
        IStreamCalculator<IVerifier> calculator = verifier.CreateCalculator();
        
        Stream sOut = calculator.Stream;
        sOut.Write(message, 0, message.Length);
        sOut.Close();
        return calculator.GetResult().IsVerified(signature);
    } 


If originalEd25519Key is not misnamed, it's for Ed25519 that is an instance of EdDSA with a certain curve, not ECDSA. Signatures and public keys of EdDSA and ECDSA are not interoperable. Nothing can be done about it.
